# How to get status description from spring boot rest controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I have a rest controller in springboot with embedded tomcat. the controller is calling from ASP .NET application where they are checking StatusDescription is "OK" or not. My response is ok with data but Status Description is always empty String.

is there any way to get StatusDescription?

example api:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/updateStatus", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CheckStatusResponse> updateStatusResponse(@RequestParam(value = "TransactionId", required = false) String transactionID,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "VenderId", required = false) String vendorId,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "Status", required = false) String transactionStatus,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "BcCode", required = false) String bcId,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "rrn", required = false) String rrn) {
        AepsTransaction transaction = new AepsTransaction();
        transaction.setTransactionId(transactionID);
        transaction.setTransactionStatus(transactionStatus);
        transaction.setRrn(rrn);
        transaction.setBcId(bcId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(aepsService.upDateStatusCallBackHandeling(transaction), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer. This problem occur for tomcat version greater than 8.5. if you downgrade your tomcat to 8.0, the problem is solved